# Define a new mathematical function in TCL using Tcl_CreateMathFunc

Tags: math, tcl

I use TCL 8.4 and for that version I need to add a new mathematical function into TCL interpreter by using TCL library function, particularly `Tcl_CreateMathFunc`. But I could not find a single example of how it can be done. Please could you write for me a very simple example, assuming that in the C code you have a `Tcl_Interp *interp` to which you should add a math function (say, a function that multiplies two double numbers).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once did some alternative implementations of random number generators for Tcl and you can look at some examples at the [git repository](http://www.patthoyts.tk/gitweb?p=Random;a=summary). The files in generic implement both a tcl command and a tcl math function for each PRNG.

So for instance in the Mersenne Twister implementation, in the package init function we add the new function to the interpreter by declaring

```
Tcl_CreateMathFunc(interp, "mt_rand", 1, (Tcl_ValueType *)NULL, RandProc, (ClientData)state);
```

this registers the C function RandProc for us. In this case the function takes no arguments but the seeding equivalent (srand) shows how to handle a single parameter.

```
/*
 * A Tcl math function that implements rand() using the Mersenne Twister
 * Pseudo-random number generator.
 */
 static int
 RandProc(ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, Tcl_Value *args, Tcl_Value *resultPtr)
 {
     State * state = (State *)clientData;
     if (! (state->flags & Initialized)) {
         unsigned long seed;
         /* This is based upon the standard Tcl rand() initializer */
         seed = time(NULL) + ((long)Tcl_GetCurrentThread()<<12);
         InitState(state, seed);
     }
     resultPtr->type = TCL_DOUBLE;
     resultPtr->doubleValue = RandomDouble(state);
     return TCL_OK;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

Be aware that this is an API that is very unlikely to survive indefinitely (for reasons such as its weird types, inflexible argument handling, and the inability to easily use it from Tcl itself). However, here's how to do an `add(x,y)` with both arguments being `double`s:

### Registration

```c
Tcl_ValueType types[2] = { TCL_DOUBLE, TCL_DOUBLE };
Tcl_CreateMathFunc(interp, "add", 2, types, AddFunc, NULL);
```

### Implementation

```c
static int AddFunc(ClientData ignored, Tcl_Interp *interp,
        Tcl_Value *args, Tcl_Value *resultPtr) {
    double x = args[0].doubleValue;
    double y = args[1].doubleValue;

    resultPtr->doubleValue = x + y;
    resultPtr->type = TCL_DOUBLE;
    return TCL_OK;
}
```

Note that because this API is always working with a fixed number of arguments to the function (and argument type conversions are handled for you) then the code you write can be pretty short. (Writing it to be type-flexible with `TCL_EITHER` — only permissible in the registration/declaration — makes things quite a lot more complex, and you really are stuck with a fixed argument count.)